# Extension OpenSSL exists in powershell but not in web server

Tags: php, apache

I'm trying to build something in Laravel really quick, and it is the strangest scenario to me but here it goes:

1. Web server is setup, using PHP 7.1. **phpinfo() And `php -v` agree**
2. `php -m` lists openssl as a module that is installed.
3. In a PHP file, both `function_exists('openssl_encrypt')` and `extension_loaded('openssl')` both return false
4. `php -r "var_dump(extension_loaded('openssl'));"` outputs true. (as does `function_exists`)

I officially admit defeat -- I've restarted my Apache service probably 10 times with no luck. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: php cli and the one used by Apache don't always share the same `php.ini`. This is most likely the case for you. What distribution do you use?

Comment: help me clarify something -- when you say distribution, you mean?

Comment: Linux distribution, or the the Apache/PHP stack you use.

Comment: oh I just used the download links for everything except mysql, which came with an installer. I setup php/apache myself.

Comment: I would run `php --ini` and see what `php.ini` file is loaded when running it from the command line. Then compare it with the web output of `phpinfo()` (there should be a ini path in there too)

Comment: ah that seems to be the issue -- apache is loading one from the `C:\WINDOWS` directory but the other one is loading the one from my server config route... weird.

Comment: mm-- maybe i stand corrected. There isn't even a php.ini file in the Windows directory.

Comment: That would explain why no extensions are loaded :-)

Comment: Except for it lists the correct php.ini file. I've never had to pay attention to that part of the php info page.